# Keras R on Rstudio server error

Tags: r, rstudio-server

I am installing keras on R studio server.

On the OS (Ubuntu 14.04, 64 bit) I opened an R session and ran

```
install.packages("keras")
install_keras()
```

Per instructions in https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/keras/.

However, when I library(keras) in the console it works.

But from the Rstudio server, browser, when I library(keras) I get the below error:

```
 Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘keras’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'keras', details:
  call: py_module_import(module, convert = convert)
  error: ImportError: No module named keras
```

I am using the same user on the OS and on the browser to launch keras.
Has anyone had this issue before? Appreciate advice on how I can resolve this.

I can also see the keras package in the packages view on the r-studio server browser.
Thanks!

Comment: Could you try following the steps listed in this [post](https://keras.rstudio.com/) and mention what step fails.

Comment: This is for someone who came to this page for help in installation of keras and tensorflow on Windows 10 in R :This helped me! https://www.r-bloggers.com/a-newbies-install-of-keras-tensorflow-on-windows-10-with-r/